# Apache camel pass headers in recipient list

Tags: java, apache-camel, dsl, spring-camel

I have the below route set with two processors defined for the route.

```
from(direct: a)
    .streamCaching()
    .process(new MyProcessorA())
    .toD(endpoint)
    .to("log:DEBUG?showBody=true&showHeaders=true")
    .log("Response from microservice: ${body}")
    .process(new MyProcessorB())
    .end()
```

and I have a REST API defined to call the routes with recipient list as follows:

```
rest()
    .post("/accumulate")
    .route()
    .process(new RequestProcessor())
    .recipientList()
    .exchangeProperty(routes)
    .endRest();
```

My recipient list will have a list of routes defined, for instance `routeA` and `routeB`. I want to set a header by extracting a response field from `routeA` and use it in `routeB`. I try to do this in my `MyProcessorB` class as follows:

```
@Component
public class MyProcessorB implements Processor {

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        exchange.setHeader("accId", "acc1234");
    }
}
```

Now when the recipient list executes `routeB` I am accessing the header set in `MyProcessorA` class, but I get it as `null`. I have set a debug point and have seen `MyProcessorB` getting called and header getting set, but why do I miss it in the next route?

Answer (score 0):

You shoud look at the routingSlip EIP.
recipientList duplicate message, routingSlip iterate sequentially on routes.
https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/routingSlip-eip.html